# Streaming error occurred org.apache.cassandra.io.FSReadError: java.io.IOException: Broken pipe

Tags: cassandra

I am trying to add a node to the cluster. Adding new node to the cluster fails with a broken pipe. Cassandra fails after starting within 2 minutes. I removed the node from the ring and adding it back fails.

OS info: 4.4.0-59-generic #80-Ubuntu SMP x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux.

This is the error I get on the node that I am trying to bootstrap. 
cassandra version - 2.2.7. Getting Broken pipe exception..

```
ERROR [STREAM-OUT-/123.120.56.71] 2017-04-10 23:46:15,410 StreamSession.java:532 - Stream #cbb7a150-1e47-11e7-a556-a98ec456f4de Streaming error occurred
org.apache.cassandra.io.FSReadError: java.io.IOException: Broken pipe
at org.apache.cassandra.io.util.ChannelProxy.transferTo(ChannelProxy.java:144) ~[apache-cassandra-2.2.7.jar:2.2.7]
at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.compress.CompressedStreamWriter$1.apply(CompressedStreamWriter.java:91) ~[apache-cassandra-2.2.7.jar:2.2. 7]
at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.compress.CompressedStreamWriter$1.apply(CompressedStreamWriter.java:88) ~[apache-cassandra-2.2.7.jar:2.2. 7]
at org.apache.cassandra.io.util.BufferedDataOutputStreamPlus.applyToChannel(BufferedDataOutputStreamPlus.java:297) ~[apache-cassandra-2.2.7 .jar:2.2.7]
at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.compress.CompressedStreamWriter.write(CompressedStreamWriter.java:87) ~[apache-cassandra-2.2.7.jar:2.2.7]
at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.messages.OutgoingFileMessage.serialize(OutgoingFileMessage.java:90) ~[apache-cassandra-2.2.7.jar:2.2.7]
at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.messages.OutgoingFileMessage$1.serialize(OutgoingFileMessage.java:48) ~[apache-cassandra-2.2.7.jar:2.2.7]
at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.messages.OutgoingFileMessage$1.serialize(OutgoingFileMessage.java:40) ~[apache-cassandra-2.2.7.jar:2.2.7]
at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.messages.StreamMessage.serialize(StreamMessage.java:47) ~[apache-cassandra-2.2.7.jar:2.2.7]
at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.ConnectionHandler$OutgoingMessageHandler.sendMessage(ConnectionHandler.java:389) ~[apache-cassandra-2.2.7 .jar:2.2.7]
at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.ConnectionHandler$OutgoingMessageHandler.run(ConnectionHandler.java:361) ~[apache-cassandra-2.2.7.jar:2.2.7]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_101]
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Broken pipe
at sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.transferTo0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
at sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.transferToDirectlyInternal(FileChannelImpl.java:428) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
at sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.transferToDirectly(FileChannelImpl.java:493) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
at sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.transferTo(FileChannelImpl.java:608) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
at org.apache.cassandra.io.util.ChannelProxy.transferTo(ChannelProxy.java:140) ~[apache-cassandra-2.2.7.jar:2.2.7]
... 11 common frames omitted
INFO [STREAM-OUT-/123.120.56.71] 2017-04-10 23:46:15,424 StreamResultFuture.java:183 - Stream #cbb7a150-1e47-11e7-a556-a98ec456f4de Session with / 123.120.56.71 is complete
WARN [STREAM-OUT-/123.120.56.71] 2017-04-10 23:46:15,425 StreamResultFuture.java:210 - Stream #cbb7a150-1e47-11e7-a556-a98ec456f4de Stream failed
```

Answer (score 1):

Can be due to corrupted data, wrong ssl configuration, schema disagreement or network failures.

Look like you have corrupted data or schema disagreement, so try the following:

1) Remove all the data from your data and commitlog directories, and then try to start.

2) If it doesn't help, try to to start with **auto_bootstrap: false** in cassandra.yaml. After the node starts and up, run **nodetool rebuild**.

If it fails, please attach all the errors here.